# What's the difference between process.cwd() vs process.env.PWD?

Tags: node.js

> Both **"return the current working directory of the process"**.

It seems you can override the value of `process.env.PWD` but it will not change the returning value of `process.cwd()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [process.env.PWD vs process.cwd()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414852/process-env-pwd-vs-process-cwd)

Answer (score 46):

`PWD` is the current working directory when the process is started, but it is constant. `process.cwd()` is asking the underlying system for the process's current directory, which can be changed with `process.chdir()`. `PWD` is also a POSIX environmental variable, which means it won't work on Windows. `process.cwd()` on the other hand, will.