# I build a nodejs command line how to know the folder where the command called

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a command line with node.js , and I need to know where the command invoked but I can't figure that out ? I tried `__dirname` but its not working , How to know the folder the command run in .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [process.cwd()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) instead of `__dirname` the difference is that __dirname returns the folder where the module ( your code ) lives and [process.cwd()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) return the directory where  the current working directory of the Node.js process. and that's useful for command lines .

Answer (score 1):

Use [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env).

It will have `PWD` (present working directory) property.

```
[09:08:51]::tmp$ pwd
/tmp
[09:08:53]::tmp$ node
> process.env.PWD
'/tmp'
```

[mostafa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50799736/691711) may actually be what you are looking for, but consider the [differences between `process.cwd()` vs `process.env.PWD`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30991319/691711) and what your use case is.

Answer (score 0):

This would return the path of the main file:

```
require('path').dirname(require.main.filename)
```

And the current working directory is

```
process.cwd()
```

The later one is the path where the script was envoked from.